# how to get the lowest float value from the hash map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a map which looks like below. What I want to do is get the minimum float value and its corresponding key. Also the float values are like for example 3127668.8 or 1.786453E7 and so on and so forth. How can I achieve this?

```
Map<String, Float> distance = new HashMap<String, Float>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String str;
Float min =Float.valueOf(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY );
for(Map.Entry<String,Float> e:distance.entrySet()){
    if(min.compareTo(e.getValue())>0){
        str=e.getKey();
        min=e.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SHiRKiT it's the best you can get without a redesign

Comment: I would only change the default value of min to `Float.MAX_VALUE`, but just because I don't know the uses nor the value of `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: @SHiRKiT [Float.compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo(java.lang.Float)) has positive infinity as larger than any representable number (check the [IEEE standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Infinities) ) but any number guaranteed to be larger than the smallest is fine I just went to the extreme

Comment: it just prints infinity and null

Comment: @Suyesh reverse the comparison (`<` becomes `>`) my bad fixed in answer

Answer (score 4):

One line of code:

```
Float min = Collections.min(distance.values());
```

It's easy to maintain by JDK library.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the entries and do a comparison.

Alternatively, use a wrapper class that does the comparison on item entry to avoid the iteration, or a map implementation that does sorting/ordering based on arbitrary criteria, etc.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String minKey = null;
Float minValue = Float.MAX_VALUE;
for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : distance.entrySet()) {
    Float value = entry.getValue();
    if (value < minValue) {
        minKey = entry.getKey();
        minValue = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the entry set of the map, i.e., distance.entrySet(), which is a collection of Map.Entry objects, which are basically a key/value pair. Something like this:

```
Map.Entry<String,Float> minEntry;
for(entry : distance.entrySet()) {
    if(minEntry == null) {
        minEntry = entry;
        continue;
    }
    if(minEntry.getValue() > entry.getValue()) {
        minEntry = entry;
    }
}
```